# evolution: sending e-mail from gmail system account

Tags: evolution, gmail, online-accounts, smtp

With last system update Evolution got Gmail integration through system online accounts, and it appeared along with my usual Evolution account for Gmail. I like integration, but when I turned usual account off, Evolution stopped to send e-mails through system account. And I don't see any setting for it in Evolution. So is there a way to answer through Evolution with system account, or should I use my old Evolution account and turn off Gmail integration if I don't want to see my e-mail box doubled?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust Settings for receiving and Sending Gmail mail in following way :

---Receiving(POP) Mail-------

> Server Type: POP
>  Server: pop.gmail.com:995
>  Username:
>   sucharitha.mahawela@gmail.com
>  Use Secure Connection: SSL
>   encryption
>  Authentication: Password Authentication

---Sending(smtp) Mail---------

> Server: smtp.gmail.com:587
>  Server requires authentication:
>   Checked
>  Security: TLS encryption
>  Authentication: Plain or
>   Login
>  Username: sucharitha.mahawela@gmail.com

Comment: Where do I adjust settings for sending for on-line account? It only have receiving.

Comment: there is no separate section as sending.Sending settings should bu adjusted in first or second section(cannot exactly remember)

Comment: @user224082 , it's true if you made account inEvo. I created account in On-line accounts Ubuntu system menu, and Evo doesn't allow me to delete it or set SMTP. =(

Answer (score 0):

When using Ubuntu 15.04, I have run into issues with Evolution being unable to send emails (using a Google Apps account) when the account is configured via Ubuntu's "online accounts" settings section instead of using Evolution's accounts setup option.

I have been successfully able to receive and send emails from Evolution (as well as sync calendars and contacts) if I set the google account from within Evolution itself.

Using Ubuntu 15.04, with the latest updated Evolution 3.16.0 version.